# How to pick up a SEAL team?

Tags: sub-command

In the "Spec Ops" mission you are required to drop off one SEAL team and pick up another.

I've been able to drop off the first team by going to the correct coordinates and raising the submarine's sail out of the water. However, I can't pick up the second team despite surfacing the sub and driving it almost over the top of them!

[image]
[image]

I've tried raising the radio antenna but that doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pickups are scripted, therefore, collecting a Special Forces team requires four things:

- Position
- Time
- Speed
- Depth

**Be sure that you're at periscope depth at the location specified in your tasking message, at the rendezvous time, at a suitably low speed.**

Comment: Depth of 45 feet, two knots seemed to do the trick. Also you can't pick up SEAL team 5 before you drop off SEAL team 3.